# Evento TextChange solo ejecuta instrucciones dentro de else: c# y asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo 4 textBox, hago una consulta a mi BD y dependiendo de lo que se seleccione en un DropDownList me debe ejecutar una multiplicación ya sea `Txt1 * Txt3` ó `Txt2 * Txt3` y me muestre el resultado en el `Txt4`.

El método es el mismo para todos los txtBox:

```
 protected void TxtImporte_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OdbcConnection cd = new OdbcConnection("xxxxx");
    cd.Open();
    DataTable dtc = new DataTable();
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT T0.ItemName FROM OITM T0 WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T0.ItmsGrpCod in (110,119) and T0.ItemName Like'%?' group by T0.ItemName", cd);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dtc);
    if (dtc.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        Double sueldo = 0;
        Double.TryParse(TxtPiezas.Text, out sueldo);

        Double remuneracion = 0;
        Double.TryParse(TxtPrecio.Text, out remuneracion);

        TxtImporte.Text = (sueldo * remuneracion).ToString("N2");

    }
    else
    {
        Double kilos = 0;
        Double.TryParse(TxtKilos.Text, out kilos);

        Double remuneracion = 0;
        Double.TryParse(TxtPrecio.Text, out remuneracion);

        TxtImporte.Text = (kilos * remuneracion).ToString("N2");
    }
}
```

Pero cuando corro la página solamente ejecuta la instrucción después de else para todos los elementos del DropDownList. Mi consulta está bien formulada pues si yo ejecuto desde sql server me dice si el producto pertenece al rango (110,119) o si no existe.

En SQL server:

```
SELECT T0.ItemName FROM OITM T0 WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T0.ItmsGrpCod in (110,119)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre se repiten algunos valores.

Comment: Siempre tiene una sola fila ese DataTable? (dtc.Rows.Count == 1??)

Comment: No se te ocurrio antes que hacer esto muy complicado, hacer un OdbcCommand.ExecuteScalar (si solo querias un resultado) o algun otro tipo de objeto? pasarlo a un adapter para despues pasarlo a un DataTable, para no hacer nada de nada con ellos, es raro...

Comment: Yo tenía `dtc.Rows.Count >= 1` porque hay 4 exepciones en donde muestra tres filas pero seguía igual, me pasa lo mismo con ExecuteScalar

Comment: ExecuteScalar devuelve el valor de la primera fila y primera columna. No entiendo bien la idea de tu query, pero como tuviste problemas con eso? o devolvio algo o devolvio nulo.. el problema es que siempre devuelve algo... lo que tenes que controlar es que devolvio... contar las filas de la respuesta no es siempre una buena idea...

Comment: Es mas, puede que la ejecucion del DT este diferida, y no se haya llenado todavia...

Comment: Si quito el DataTable y solamente ejecuto con ExecuteScalar de esta manera: ´  int a = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (a == 1)´ sigue tomando únicamente else aún cuando selecciono un valor del DropDownList que esté en el rango (110,119)

Comment: Pero a que valor tiene? hiciste un debug?

Comment: Lo declaro como variable igualando cmd.ExecuteScalar para utilizarlo en el if pero nada. Tengo un problema con hacer debug en vs 2017

Comment: Como que tenes un problema? si pones un punto de interrupcion ahi, deberias poder ver el valor que toma.

Comment: Sale un mensaje de error que dice `No se puede iniciar el programa. Existe una operación que no es legar en el estado actual.`

Comment: @Elizabeth podrias colocar el script que generas que campos hay en es select valor

Comment: @Elizabeth para poder ayudarte

Comment: Esperen.. vamos por partes.. Googlea ese error, que tiene un monton de soluciones para que intentes... despues, dime que valor tiene a.. ese valor es el que estas buscando y te genera problemas...

Comment: por que no intentas utilizar un ODBCDataReader ? y utilizar el metodo read ? : While(reader.read())  de esta manera puedes obtener fila por fila los datos que retorna el query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para objetos locales no me gusta utilizar un DataAdapter para leer información, sobre todo si el datatable va a ser temporal y local (Mucha Arquitectura para algo muy simple)

en su lugar par lecturas sencillas prefiero utilizar un datareader o un ExecuteScalar

```
     OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT T0.ItemName FROM OITM T0 WHERE T0.TreeType = 'T' and T0.ItmsGrpCod in (110,119) and T0.ItemName Like'%?' group by T0.ItemName", cd);



    OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    bool hayDatos=reader.HasRows; //para saber si hay resultados
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Obtuvimos Datos!, ahora a extraerlos 
        //como es odbc puede que hasrows nos diga false hasta que ejecutemos el metodo Read
          hayDatos= true;
          reader["T0.ItemName"].ToString();// (aunque recomendaria ponerle alias al resultado por que esto puede que falle dependiendo del driver...
    }


if (hayDatos == true )
{
    Double sueldo = 0;
    Double.TryParse(TxtPiezas.Text, out sueldo);

    Double remuneracion = 0;
    Double.TryParse(TxtPrecio.Text, out remuneracion);

    TxtImporte.Text = (sueldo * remuneracion).ToString("N2");

}
else
{
    Double kilos = 0;
    Double.TryParse(TxtKilos.Text, out kilos);

    Double remuneracion = 0;
    Double.TryParse(TxtPrecio.Text, out remuneracion);

    TxtImporte.Text = (kilos * remuneracion).ToString("N2");
}
```

Comment: Justamente fijate en los comentarios. Probo con esto y tampoco le funciono. el problema esta en otro lado.

Comment: ese ultimo error parece mas bien ser un problema de depuración. 
Estoy sospechando que el problema esta en el driver

Comment: Esto soluciono el problema??!?!????